# remove empty line in case of int

Tags: java, swing, blank-line

I am removing empty lines from text file using this code:

```
PrintWriter text= new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( result+".txt", false)));
String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
               if (!line.equals(""))
               {
                text.write(line, 0, line.length());
               }
            }
```

And it works, but in case of:

```
text2= new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "result2.txt", false)));
int temp;
    while( ( temp = sistream.read() ) != -1){
        //is it possible to have empty integer?
     { 
     System.out.print( (char) temp );
      text2.write(temp);
 }     
    }
```

In case of `int` it gives me error.

I don't know, is it possible to have empty `int`?

How to remove empty line in case of `int`?

Thanks.

Error that I got:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: <any>
    at project.Mergefiles.merge(Mergefiles.java:66)
    at project.Main2.exforActionPerformed(Main2.java:623)
    at project.Main2.access$500(Main2.java:52)
    at project.Main2$9.actionPerformed(Main2.java:321)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? stacktrace?

Comment: @ Aniket Thakur int cannot be dereferenced

Comment: Are you sure the error is in above piece of code. It would be helpful if you could add the stacktrace  in your question.

Comment: It is not possible to have an empty int in this case since every character in your file is represented by a value. I'm not 100% sure but I think so.